# AAD guest users are not allowed to be account owners

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have custom AAD and I added my company account to the AAD. I made the company account owner of the subscription and administrator of the AAD.

When I want to create new Team Project, the deployment fails with message:

> VS850006: AAD guest users are not allowed to be account owners. Please
> use a non-guest AAD user. AAD guest user sign-in address:
> john.doe@contoso.com (Code: OrganizationBadRequestException)

It was working yesterday before I made myself AAD administrator. WTF?

Comment: Check this feedback: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/53484/could-not-change-vsts-azure-ad.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably a guest in the AAD that backs VSTS. By default AAD guests cannot search the AAD.

You could check your user type on Azure Portal.`Azure Active Directory`-->`All Users`-->`<your user>`-->`profile`
[image]

f the UserType is GUEST, you can make this user a MEMBER by executing

```
Set-Msoluser -UserPrincipalName <your ID> -usertype member
```

More information about this please refer to this [blog]

Update:

If your account is a Microsoft account, you could use [Azure AD Power Shell 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) to change user type.

```
Connect-Azuread -TenantID "****************"
Get-azureaduser -ObjectID "99f1721e-42ae-4056-9c14-30976aa1608b"|Set-AzureADUser -UserType "member"
```

(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2015/12/23/issues-with-azure-active-directory-guest-users-in-aad-backed-visual-studio-team-services-accounts/).

Comment: When I run `Connect-MsolService` and enter my company credentials, it connects me to the company AAD where I'm member. How do I connect to the project AAD, where the user is guest?

Comment: Do you mean they use the same user account?

Comment: If my understanding is right, on your company AAD, the account role is member. You invite the account to your custom AAD, by default the role should be guest. You should login your custom AD portal and check the user's role.

Comment: `Connect-MsolService` connect your custom AAD not your company AAD.

Comment: Yes, I was invited to the custom ADD as a guest and given global-administrator role. However, I'm still guest when I check it in portal.
Anyway, I'm having troubles to connect to the custom AAD with the command line, since the login dialog won't accept mydomainname@hotmail.com username. It has to be something user@domain.onmicrosoft.com...

Comment: Maybe I could do it from the Azure Portal -> Cloud Shell -> Bash -> Azure CLI 2?

Comment: @Liero Sorry for the later reply. No, it is not possible. You could use Azure AD PowerShell 2.0. You could check my answer.

Comment: @Liero I test in my lab, I meet the same issue with you, use Azure AD powershell could solve this issue.

Comment: Just noticed the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114970/how-to-i-connect-to-aad-using-powershell) you asked. Do you use the hotmail.com to login your Azure Portal. For old MSOL module, you should use Azure AD account to login, so Microsoft account could not login. For Azure AD powerShell 2.0, it supports hotmail.com account.

Comment: Please ensure you use a same account when your login Azure Portal and Azure AD powerShell 2.0.

Comment: I've solved the login issue by creating new local user in the AAD, making him global admin and use that login with powershell in order to change the Guest user to Member. But even then I was getting `AAD guest users are not allowed to be account owners`. I guess it takes some time to reflect this change in VSTS?

Comment: @Liero Do you check it on Azure Portal, the User type is `member`. I suggest you could wait for a moment.

Comment: But for Azure AD PowerShell V2, you could login with Microsoft account.

Comment: Yes, I've checked. I waited an hour or two. I'm overall very disappointed with all those limitation and complexity of administration tasks. All of this is just nonsense

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues and these were the powershell commands that helped:

`Install-Module AzureAD
Install-Module MSOnline
Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module MSOnline
$AzureAdCred = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $AzureAdCred
Connect-MSolService -Credential $AzureAdCred
Set-MsolUser -ObjectId <your-account-id> -UserType Member`

I could not connect immediately but after waiting for a few hours (8 in my case) connecting the account worked.

If you want to make sure that the object-id you are using is the correct user you want to alter you can use the following command:
`Get-MsolUser -ObjectId <your-account-id>`