# How to I connect to AAD using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have an hotmail account myaccount123@hotmail.com associated with Azure subscription and AAD (Default Directory - myaccount123hotmail.onmicrosoft.com).

When I execute `Connect-MsolService` in Microsoft AAD module for PowerShell, a login popup appears, but I'm not able to login with my hotmail credentials. Login says:

> hotmail.com isn't in our system

Comment: Not sure about the old MSOL module, have you tried the new Azure AD v2 powershell module?

Comment: Yes, just now. Exactly the same output

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup as you where my hotmail account (Microsoft account) is also associated with Azure subscription and AAD.

Here's the **AzureAD PowerShell module** which I am using - `Version 2.0.0.131`
[image]

When I run `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet, I am able to login with my hotmail account and get the result as shown:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your login was remembered?  Did you entered your hotmail email address or account name ending with .onmicrosoft.com? I solved it by creating new service account in the aad.

Comment: No, i only use my hotmail to login via the Azure AAD connect when I try for your case. As shown, I use account end with hotmail.com